# How would one successfully change the font of a header/paragraph in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fonts

Hope you're having a great day. I'm trying to make my site more accessible, but I really love this one font. However, it's hard to read for some people. I'm making a button to change all the fonts to an easier to read font, but I'm having trouble creating that code.

I've tried `document.getElementById('header').style.fontFamily = "font-family: 'Rambla', sans-serif"` (and all of the other DOM selectors there too), But they either don't work with no errors, or it errors.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
function fontChange() {
  document.getElementById('header').style.fontFamily = "font-   family: 'Rambla', sans-serif"
  console.log('Works?')
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">What are the parameters for the /scheme command?</h1>
<button id="fontChange" onclick="fontChange()">
  
</button>
```

Comment: See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#setting_styles). `"font-family: 'Rambla', sans-serif"` isn’t a set of font families. `"'Rambla', sans-serif"` is.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Aha, whoops. Messed up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ?

```
    <h1 id="header">What are the parameters for the /scheme command?</h1>
<button id="fontChange" onclick="fontChange()">
  
</button>
<script>
    function fontChange() {
           document.getElementById('header').style.fontFamily = "Rambla"
        console.log('Works?')
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I advice you to toggle a global class on body element for example.

```
document.body.classList.add('accessible-font');
```

Then it would give you more possibilities and easier integration using some stylesheets :

```
.accessible-font #header {
  font-family: 'Rambla', sans-serif";
}
```

You can then define some global or specific rules based on this global class. It also allows you to easilly switch between a11y ON / OFF.

Comment: Oh, that's really smart! Thanks for your help, I'm definitely going to try that :D

Comment: I don't understand, It actually doesn't work. However, I would have gone with this one if it did. :D

Comment: @InterConnect Of course it works, given the corrected spelling.